# Blogger template not showing more than 7 posts per page

Tags: blogger

So I'm building a blog on Blogger and I downloaded a free template "Cleansis template" but it keeps showing 6 or 7 posts per page. I tried increasing the posts from the layout section to no avail and I'm a total newbie to blogger. Any help would be nice.

-Here I increased the number of posts to 20

[image: This is where I increase the number of posts displayed on the page]

Yet when I visit the blog, it shows just 6 posts.

I tried going into the xml code of the template to increase the value of the pageCount variable but it just works wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to say, you want to display more number of posts under Popular posts gadget or Featured Posts gadget or are you using some other add-on? Please specify little more

Comment: No on the main blog area. I want it to display more posts, maybe I should add screenshots

Comment: "http://sparksnaija.com" - that's the blog URL. It uses a template called "Cleansis template"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one trick which you can give a try which is by inserting JUMP breaks.

So, steps are like this:

**1. Go into edit mode of each of your posts from 1 to 10 or from 1 to 20, whatever number of posts you want to display on the main page.**

**2. Then in each post, after the 1st paragraph ends, add a Jump break into it. Look below into the screenshot. Jump break is present near the RED ARROW and we want to add it near the YELLOW ARROW.**

[image]

**3. After that, it will look like this below. Then click on Update to save your changes.**

[image]

**4. Repeat this process for all the remaining posts and then check on your main page.**

FYI, you can check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rmae2M1xFiM) also

Hope this will help..!!!!

Comment: Thank you so much Nish, this totally solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Place Jump Breaks on after the first paragraphs of about 8-10 posts including some of the ones refusing to show up on their page. Solves it.